# Is there a way to add git alias of customized log to magit?

Tags: magit

In `~./gitconfig`, I have

```
[alias]
lg1 = log --graph --abbrev-commit --decorate --format=format:'%C(bold blue)%h%C(reset) - %C(bold green)(%ar)%C(reset) %C(white)%s%C(reset) %C(dim white)- %an%C(reset)%C(bold yellow)%d%C(reset)' --all
```

In magit, when type `ll`, it will log differently.

Is there a way to add another keystroke combination (such as `lL`) in magit to do customization log as `lg1` above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to add additional commands to the log popup (or any other of its popup), but it would be far from trivial to implement your alias as a Magit command. It is not enough to pass the desired arguments to `git`, something then also has to parse the output. This is done in one of the darker corners of Magit, see `magit-log-wash-rev`. You would have to edit that function and add a new `magit-log-*-re` variable.

So no, in practice you cannot do what you want to do.

However you might not have to.  Are you aware that you can show additional information in the *margin*, including the author and commit date? That seems to cover the additional information you want to display. See the documentation about the [log margin](https://magit.vc/manual/magit/Log-Margin.html).

Comment: Thanks for your detail explaination! Though it is not doable currently, I find magit's `la` shows similar info as `lg1`